# May a Pakistaini apply for a Turkish visa while in the USA?

Tags: turkey, applications, pakistani-citizens, us-residents, e-visas

I am a Pakistani national and residing permanently(Green Card) in USA.  How can and where to apply for turkish visa.(An official turkish visa web site address)

Answer (score 2):

I searched for "Apply for visa to Turkey" on the internet using Google. The search returned a list of web pages. The second item in the list was the Republic of Turkey's Ministry of Foreign Affairs [eVisa application page](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/).

As a Pakistani citizen holding valid residence permit from USA, you are eligible for an eVisa and can obtain one from within the comfort of your home for **USD $60**.